# Map-making software

Tags: software, tools, world-building

I'm looking for free software, preferably open-source, that would allow me to create maps for my story. I guess what I need is a tool that would allow some measure of 3D modeling.

Features I would very much like:

- Fiddling with elevation
- Drawing rivers, and making sure they don't do silly things like flowing upwards.
- Marking precipitation, so that, for myself, I know "region X is arid".
- Marking roads, cities, forests, etc.
- Measuring distances
- Generating some sort of 2D map out of the 3D model

Is there anything in existence that's sort of in the right direction, perhaps some tool for RPGs?

I will need a map with my novel, eventually, but primarily this is for myself and my worldbuilding at this stage: I want to make sure I'm consistent with distances and with routes. Also, the story is relatively heavy on geopolitics, making a map rather critical for the creative process. (This is apparently what happens when the MC is the king, and he does actual governing.)

Comment: I'm thinking this is a better fit for Worldbuilding.  Better doesn't mean it doesn't go here, but I'm not sure it does go here.  Of course there it would be a duplicate.  They have several questions like this.

Comment: Agreed.  It should probably be worldbuilding.SE -- there's an app that I know that's great for RPGs called Archivos (https://archivos.digital/ ) that works WITH maps and linking events/characters to locations.  Also, the guy in charge of it (Dave Robson) posted on his personal facebook lately about some map-designing tool he's been working with, so that may be worth tracking down,  (I can't use FB at work to be more specific).

Comment: @April Archivos incorporates *existing* maps. I need to *create* them, from scratch. The question *might* also be on topic in [worldbuilding.se] - I'm not really active there, donno, but it's hardly off topic here, is it?

Comment: I would suggest this is more on-topic at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ than Worldbuilding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because map-making software is not a *writing* tool.

Comment: @Chappo I guess I'm thinking of worldbuilding as an integral part of [tag:planning] my story, including ongoing and continuing building of it. Sort of pre-writing. So I'm looking for software that would help me do that. We allow questions about software for organising worldbuilding (e.g.: https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/31264/14704), is the map element too far from that? I mean, as I understand it, [worldbuilding.se] is all about "how do I have X in my world". My question is about "what software can help me have this planning/visualisation thing for my **worldbuilding process**".

Comment: I appreciate that it's in the grey zone, but the existence of a similar question doesn't mean our site "allows" such questions: if I'd seen it, I'd have flagged the other one too. The issue is: where do we draw the line? Questions about image-editing software for books with images? Web design software for people designing blogs? Family tree software for writing family histories? The point is that good writing relies on research, but *WritingSE may not be the place to do that research*. If I have a question about grammar or literary analysis for my book/essay, I can't ask it here. ...

Comment: ... Anyway, I'm not the final arbiter on this, and I see it as part of the process for our site establishing/clarifying/defining our boundaries before we move beyond beta. I only voted to close after carefully reading the on-topic page, including the linked answer on [avoiding *idea generation*](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1272/21181), so my VTC was a *considered decision*. In any case, if others vote to leave your question open, that's fine - and will give me a better sense of what WritingSE allows.

Comment: @Chappo fair enough, I accept that it is borderline. But I would also accept the family tree software question. Those are such an integral element of the fantasy genre... And yeh, borderline cases are how we find out and define the limits of what we allow.

Comment: I asked in gamedev chat and one person mentioned Unity, perlin noise and blender. Not sure if any of those would help you.

Comment: I suggest you check out [What software is available for map creation?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/125/29) on [worldbuilding.se]. More generally, [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations+map-making) and [this](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-recommendations+map-making) search are both likely to be of interest to you.

Answer (score 5):

[Tiled](https://www.mapeditor.org/) is an RPG map editor. It is completely free. It works with tilemaps which can be sourced for free but may be more challenging for you because of your peculiar use case. The program is fairly versatile and I have yet to fully explore its many features. You might have to get creative to do what you need, but it should be manageable. Tilemaps are often made to allow for representing changes in terrain. It also supports notetaking. 3D options do not appear to be available.

As for tilemaps, I get mine from [OpenGameArt](https://opengameart.org/), but there are other sources in the answers to [this Gamedev.SE question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20/where-can-i-find-free-sprites-and-images).